# Blasphemy Against the Holy Spirit

Tags: nature-of-god, new-testament

If someone is saved, and they may have mistakenly or unknowingly committed blasphemy against the Holy Spirit, is his/her salvation in question? Is he/her no longer saved or welcomed in the kingdom of God?

I ask this because blasphemy is the only sin that is unforgiven.

Mark 3:29 - "But whoever blasphemes against the Holy Spirit will never be forgiven; he is guilty of an eternal sin".

Answer (score 2):

Blasphemy against The Holy Spirit is not something you would do unknowingly or mistakenly. To blaspheme against The Holy Spirit you must know that He exists, as did the Apostles. Being saved isn't the bar for this it is a knowledge much greater than that it is to know as if you had seen it with your own eyes.

It would be like Cain who lied to God and knew he was God, you must commit the sin with full knowledge of what you are doing and you do it on purpose with your own agency.

Comment: Paul did it, and was saved!

Comment: No Saul did it, and Saul did not have the knowledge required to commit blasphemy against the holy ghost until he became Paul at which point he never blasphemed against it.